Serialization of interface typed members with Parquet.net
With Parquet.net, is there a way to serialize types whose any member is interface typed?
I get a NotImplementedException in MakeField.
using Parquet.Serialization;

//using MemoryStream stream = new();
//await ParquetSerializer.SerializeAsync([new LineOK ()], stream);

using MemoryStream stream = new();
await ParquetSerializer.SerializeAsync([new LineKO()], stream);

interface IPoint
{
    decimal X { get; set; }
    decimal Y { get; set; }
}

class Point : IPoint
{
    public decimal X { get; set; }
    public decimal Y { get; set; }
}

class LineOK
{
    public Point Start { get; } = new();
    public Point End { get; } = new();
}

class LineKO
{
    public IPoint Start { get; } = new Point();
    public IPoint End { get; } = new Point();
}

I think I understand the logical issue: in a set of objects we could have different implementations hence Parquet columns/schemas.
But in the case there is a single implementation in the dataset is there a way to force the serialization?
Otherwise what are my options?
Maybe a dedicated DTO:
using MemoryStream stream = new();
await ParquetSerializer.SerializeAsync([new LineDto(new LineKO())], stream);

class LineDto
{
    public Point Start { get; }
    public Point End { get; }

    public LineDto(LineKO lineKo)
    {
        Start = (Point)lineKo.Start;
        End = (Point)lineKo.End;
    }
}

